# Trying to create a site column which have its display name as "Author" will raise "The column name that you entered is already in use or reserved.."

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-column, pnp-powershell

I am working on a sharepoint online site collection, and using the UI i have created a new site column with the following name "HRAuthor", and i save the new column. so i got a site column which have its display and its internal name as "HRAuthor". then i wanted to modify the display name of the column to be "Author". so i went to the site column, i edit it, i chnage the name from "HRAuthor" to "Author", but i got this error message:-

> The column name that you entered is already in use or reserved. Choose
>   another name.

so i am not sure if i can overcome this problem using pnp script or other means. Now i want the internal name & static name to be the same (HRAuthor), but the display name to be "Author"..

Comment: Add a space to the end. So "Author " as the display name

Comment: @theChrisKent i find another way, where i can create the site column using pnp script , in this case i can define the display name as Author, without getting any error!!

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it solved. If you post your solution as an answer to your own question, that will help out others with similar issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add fields using the `Add-PnPField` method or using the `Add-PnPFieldFromXml` as below:

1) Using `PnPField`:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://sitecollectionurl"
Add-PnPField -Type "User" -DisplayName "Author" -InternalName "HRAuthor"
```

2) Using `PnPFieldFromXml`:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://sitecollectionurl"
$web = Get-PnPWeb
$xml = '<Field Type="User" Name="HRAuthor" ID="{27d81055-f208-41c9-a976-61c5473eed4a}" DisplayName="Author" Group="Test" Required="FALSE" StaticName="HRAuthor"/>'
Add-PnPFieldFromXml -FieldXml $xml -Web $web
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter New name and run this in browser console

```
function ValidateAndSubmit() {  
       return true; 
    }
    function doesFieldNameConflict(strName) {
        return false; 
    }
```

You will be now able to save the name.